# Line up radio buttons in Bootstrap 3, regardless of label length

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel element in which I have 5 rows of radio buttons, options 1-5.  I'd like all of these rows to line up with each other, regardless of the width of their corresponding labels.  I've tried plain Bootstrap 3, jQuery UI's position API, and jQuery Mobile's 5-column grid thing.

For your perusal: http://jsfiddle.net/Muzical/yjyes5rm/2/
So for one example:

```
<label class="control-label">Criteria 1&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="Tooltip"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ui-grid-d" data-toggle="buttons">
        <div class="btn btn-default ui-block-a label">
            <input class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" type="radio" name="thing1" id="criteria1Rdo1" value="1" />1</div>
        <div class="btn btn-default ui-block-b label">
            <input class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" type="radio" name="thing1" id="criteria1Rdo2" value="2" />2</div>
        <div class="btn btn-default ui-block-c label">
            <input class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" type="radio" name="thing1" id="criteria1Rdo3" value="3" />3</div>
        <div class="btn btn-default ui-block-d label">
            <input class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" type="radio" name="thing1" id="criteria1Rdo4" value="4" />4</div>
        <div class="btn btn-default ui-block-e label">
            <input class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" type="radio" name="thing1" id="criteria1Rdo5" value="5" />5</div>
    </div>
```

I also refuse to use layout tables because that's just plain evil and this isn't 1998.  What I'd LIKE to have happen is that all of the buttons line up with the widest label and works on mobile, probably nothing smaller than an iPad mini or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a moron; hacking Bootstrap 3's column tags seems to have worked well enough (OK, IE's being a pain, but...)

http://www.bootply.com/qy6Iag0Z9E

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your html a little and use the class form-horizontal on the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/vandigroup/3oepryn4/1/

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="thing1"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="thing1"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="thing1"> Option 3
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="thing1"> Option 4
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="thing1"> Option 5
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Form-inline is already applied; this is part of a much larger evaluation form. My form tag is `<form id="form" class="form form-horizontal form-inline" role="form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onSubmit="return false;">`

Comment: @Janet then simply try putting the radio inputs INSIDE of the label. They should then all line up horizontally.

Comment: Each row lines up fine; that's not my thing.  I mean all of the radio buttons on each row I'd like to get lined up.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not understanding what you are trying to do. Using the code I supplied with make all of the radio button line up on each row EXCEPT when the screen size collapses to a point they will not all fit which at that time, they will wrap. Are you trying to prevent them from wrapping at all? Please clarify or throw up a screenshot so I can see what you are talking about.

Comment: This was pre-button-groups, but you get the idea: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48ojwpko0i0f8e1/panelLayoutIssue.png)  I do generically stink at explaining anything...so that's not you.

Comment: @Janet I see what you are talking about now although not sure what would be causing the issue. Is it padding or margin on the row, the column, the first element, etc.?? If you can post a link to this or try to get a fiddle up then I can figure out what is causing this. I would start by using dev tools and see what's different between the rows and radios inside each.